# Do SELECT (without ORDER BY) return the same message as RECEIVE?

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

My current client needs to be able to PEEK messages in a SQL Server Service Broker queue. The current implementation uses RECEIVE and rollback to peek.

As that generates writes to the transaction log I'm wondering if a SELECT TOP(1) would return the same row as the RECEIVE command?

There are several writers but just one reader to that queue.

Answer (score 5):

No. RECEIVE constructs a query AST that cannot be constructed with SELECT. RECEIVE has to guarantee EOIO and conversation group locking, SELECT does not.

Service Broker has a built-in 'peek': [`GET CONVERSATION GROUP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178624.aspx). This will lock the next available conversation group, on which you are guaranteed to get a message if you issue a RECEIVE *within the same transaction*. I strongly discourage the use of it.

Anything else you're trying to do is broken and you need to change the application to stop doing it. Always issue a RECEIVE and react to the returned messages result set.

Comment: In this case I do not care about exactly once but only about the order. Will it be the same for the SELECT?

Comment: No. Aside from the issue of asking `does SELECT without ORDER BY guarantee an order`, even if you would try to add an ORDER BY, there is no ORDER BY you could add to match a RECEIVE. But the point is moot. You shouldn't try to do it.

Comment: A select without an order by is sorted by the clustered index, right?